# Walking from Macugnaga to Saas-Fee

Tags: hiking, europe, alps

We're planning a trip to walk from Macugnaga (Italy) to Saas-Fee (Switzerland), probably as a 2-day hike over the Monte Moro pass through the Alps. The trip is planned for August 2015.

Has anyone done this route, and have any local details that might come in handy?

Comment: You were able to do it? Maybe you can answer the question by yourself now to help others planning to do the same.

Comment: I think this is a very common route, that needs no extraordinary planning. Of course you should consider the weather etc but then ...just follow all the others . [See this picture ... you can't get lost :)](http://www.sac-saas.ch/Tourenprogramm/Tourenberichte2012/images/Maria_zum_Schnee4.JPG)